# How to enable widget layout hints and code generation in Android Studio flutter project?

Tags: flutter

How to enable widget layout hints and code generation similar to one in the pic below?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly download the Flutter plugin for Android Studio. Steps for that are mentioned [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/editor).

Once you have successfully installed the plugin, you move the cursor to your desired widget and press `Alt` + `Enter` (`Option` + `Enter` on Mac) on your machine to access the widget options menu.

Also, for other IDE options for Flutter in Android Studio or IntelliJ IDEA, you can refer [this](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/android-studio) page.

Comment: Option + Enter lists the class details. I am looking for layout suggestions like in the popup in the image I posted in my question.

Comment: AFAIK the `Option` + `Enter/Return` shortcut works for the wrap code menu popup by default. The shortcut may have been reassigned on your machine. 

Keyboard mappings can be changed in the IDE Preferences/Settings: Select Keymap, then enter flutter into the search box in the upper right corner.

Comment: Great. If my answer was helpful, please mark it as accepted by clicking the green check button next to the answer. Cheers!